# Python optimize how to find duplicate value and value index in a list

Tags: python, performance, list, optimization, duplicates

I have a list with 18 000 unique ID.
ID are the concatenation of letters `A, B, C, D`.
I have made a code who group ID by `ID[0:-1]` and give index position of the duplicate ID.

That's works well but it's very long to proceed : around `110 secs` for `18 000 ID`.
Would you have an idea to speed up my code ?

```
a = ['1CDABCABDA', '1CDABCABDB', '1CDABCABDD', '1BCABCCCAA', '1DDAABBBBA', '1BCABCCCAD']

startTime = time.time()
b = [i[0:-1] for i in a]
b = list(set(b))


result = range(len(b))
it = 0
for i in result:
    result[i] = [b[i], []]
    for j in xrange(len(a)):
        if b[i] == a[j][0:-1]:
            result[i][1].append(j)

endTime =  time.time()

print endTime - startTime, 'secs !'
```

Output :

```
>>> [['1CDABCABD', [0, 1, 2]], ['1DDAABBBB', [4]], ['1BCABCCCA', [3, 5]]]
```

Comment: Can you show the output of your code?

Comment: >>> [['1CDABCABD', [0, 1, 2]], ['1DDAABBBB', [4]], ['1BCABCCCA', [3, 5]]]

Comment: You need to explain more about your code and the out put, for example what is 4 in `['1DDAABBBB', [4]]`?

Comment: It's the index position in a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a more Pythonic way for such problems use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> new=[i[:-1] for i in a]

>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> for i,j in enumerate(new):
...    d[j].append(i)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'1CDABCABD': [0, 1, 2], '1DDAABBBB': [4], '1BCABCCCA': [3, 5]})
>>> d.items()
[('1CDABCABD', [0, 1, 2]), ('1DDAABBBB', [4]), ('1BCABCCCA', [3, 5])]
```

*Note* that `defaultdict` is a linear solution and is more efficient than `itertools.groupby` and `sorted`.

Also you can just use `dict.setdefault` method :

```
>>> d={}
>>> for i,j in enumerate(new):
...   d.setdefault(j,[]).append(i)
... 
>>> d
{'1CDABCABD': [0, 1, 2], '1DDAABBBB': [4], '1BCABCCCA': [3, 5]}
```

For more details checkout the following bench marking Its **~4X** faster :

```
s1="""
from itertools import groupby
a = ['1CDABCABDA', '1CDABCABDB', '1CDABCABDD', '1BCABCCCAA', '1DDAABBBBA', '1BCABCCCAD']
key = lambda i: a[i][:-1]
indexes = sorted(range(len(a)), key=key)
result = [[x, list(y)] for x, y in groupby(indexes, key=key)]
"""
s2="""
a = ['1CDABCABDA', '1CDABCABDB', '1CDABCABDD', '1BCABCCCAA', '1DDAABBBBA', '1BCABCCCAD']
new=[i[:-1] for i in a]
d={}
for i,j in enumerate(new):
   d.setdefault(j,[]).append(i)
d.items()
    """


print ' first: ' ,timeit(stmt=s1, number=100000)
print 'second : ',timeit(stmt=s2, number=100000)
```

result :

```
 first:  0.949549913406
second :  0.250894069672
```

Comment: 0,11 secs for 18 000 ID !

Comment: @Guilhain So just feel free and accept the answer ;)

Comment: s2 is the best solution i made 10 000 iteration with 18 000 id with timeit it take 16.46 secs. Congrats !

Answer (score 5):

This is what [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in python does efficiently:

```
from itertools import groupby
a = ['1CDABCABDA', '1CDABCABDB', '1CDABCABDD', '1BCABCCCAA', '1DDAABBBBA', '1BCABCCCAD']
key = lambda i: a[i][:-1]
indexes = sorted(range(len(a)), key=key)
result = [[x, list(y)] for x, y in groupby(indexes, key=key)]
```

Output:

```
[['1BCABCCCA', [3, 5]], ['1CDABCABD', [0, 1, 2]], ['1DDAABBBB', [4]]]
```

Comment: @Guilhain Just try also Kasra's solution

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution that doesn't use other modules:

```
grouped = {}
for i, j in enumerate(a):    
    itm = grouped.get(j[0:-1], [])
    itm.append(i)    
    grouped[j[0:-1]] = itm

print [[k, v] for k, v in grouped.items()] # [['1CDABCABD', [0, 1, 2]], ['1DDAABBBB', [4]], ['1BCABCCCA', [3, 5]]]
```

Comment: @Guilhain If you like it raise your hands, clap twice, upvote and accept please ! :D

Comment: Wait but you need to return indexes... Just a technicality...But don't know how times are going to be affected...

Comment: @JuniorCompressor do you mean, `print grouped.keys()` ?

Comment: You should return sth like `[['1CDABCABD', [0, 1, 2]]...`

Comment: @JuniorCompressor oh you mean: `[[k, v] for k, v in grouped.items()]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for ind, elem in enumerate(a):
    ... d.setdefault(elem[0:-1], []).append(ind)
>>> print d
{'1CDABCABD': [0, 1, 2], '1DDAABBBB': [4], '1BCABCCCA': [3, 5]}
```

The solution is very similar to Kasra's optimized code, but works slightly faster. The difference lies in where the slicing was done, though not sure why is one performing slightly better than the other:

```
s1 = """
a = ['1CDABCABDA', '1CDABCABDB', '1CDABCABDD', '1BCABCCCAA',
      '1DDAABBBBA', '1BCABCCCAD']
d = {}
for ind, elem in enumerate(a):
    d.setdefault(elem[0:-1], []).append(ind)
"""

s2="""
a = ['1CDABCABDA', '1CDABCABDB', '1CDABCABDD', '1BCABCCCAA', '1DDAABBBBA', '1BCABCCCAD']
new=[i[:-1] for i in a]
d={}
for i,j in enumerate(new):
   d.setdefault(j,[]).append(i)
"""

print 'Kasra's time/my time: %s' % (str(timeit(stmt=s2, number=100000)/timeit(stmt=s1, number=100000))

Kasra's time/my time: 1.24058060531
```